# Selenium + Chrome Driver drag and drop not working properly

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 3.14 and ChromeDriver 2.42 with Chrome 69.0. I was always using this code to drag and drop, which worked until recently, when tests started failing:

```
$driver->action()->clickAndHold()->moveByOffset(100, 0)->release()->perform();
```

After some Chrome update, it just stopped dragging. I also tried `dragAndDropBy()` function, with no luck. (`dragAndDrop()` is not an option because I need to move inside one element).

Answer (score 2):

After hours of experimenting I was able to narrow the issue down to this weird thing, when using moveByOffset with bigger number, like `100` in my example fails, it just weirdly bounces in place. But when I tried to move it only by couple of px, it worked.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
$driver->action()->clickAndHold()->perform();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
      //moving this 10 times by 10 px instead of once by 100px
      $driver->action()->moveByOffset(10, 0)->perform(); 
}
sleep(1);
$driver->action()->release()->perform();
```

I just want to share this, if somebody encountered similar issue.